# jgraphx: hierarchical layout reduce distance between nodes

Tags: java, jgraphx, jgraph

I'm using jgraphx to visualize a control low inside a method. Thus, i'm using the `mxHierarchicalLayout`. But in the result graph the distance between two nodes is too big. (see img)

[image]

I want to reduce the yellow marked areas.

Im adding nodes with:

```
Object v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, u.toString(), u.toString(), 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

to set them all to the same spot. Afterwards im using the mxHierarchicalLayout:

```
// define layout
mxIGraphLayout layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);
// layout graph
layout.execute(graph.getDefaultParent());
```

is there a way to compress the graph ui?

Answer (score 1):

There are two parameters to define spacing between nodes on a **hierarchical layout**:

- *intraCellSpacing* for **horizontal** spacing
- *interRankCellSpacing* for **vertical** spacing (space between ranks,layers,hierarchy)

So, you are looking for the second one.

A compact example:

```
var layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);
layout.edgeStyle=2;
layout.intraCellSpacing=20;
layout.interRankCellSpacing=40;
```

[Compact mxGraph with hierarchical layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MtiG.png)

An expanded example:

```
var layout = new mxHierarchicalLayout(graph);
layout.edgeStyle=4;
layout.intraCellSpacing=20;
layout.interRankCellSpacing=70;
```

[Expanded mxGraph with hierarchical layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Fbi4.png)

You can see there is another parameter in the examples *edgeStyle* that defines different styles of the edges

For more information, take a look at [mxGraph Hierarchical layout documentation](https://jgraph.github.io/mxgraph/docs/js-api/files/layout/hierarchical/mxHierarchicalLayout-js.html#mxHierarchicalLayout.interRankCellSpacing)

Kind Regards